# SoapSerializationEnvelope version Error - KSOAP2 - Android

Tags: web-services, android-studio, version, ksoap2

I'm new to Android, so I don't have much experience. I have been looking for posts related to this error, but couldn't find any solutions.

I'm trying to connect to a VB.net web service using KSOAP2 library. I'm using Android Studio.

I'm getting an error in this method:

```
private final SoapSerializationEnvelope getSoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapObject request) {
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.implicitTypes = true;
    envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    return envelope;
}
```

The error occurs on this line:

`SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);`

I'm getting the following error:

```
05-20 12:22:43.062 1784-1784/com.example.joria.wsandroid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.joria.wsandroid, PID: 1784
                                                                       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:289)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: org/ksoap2/SoapEnvelope
                                                                           at com.example.joria.wsandroid.MainActivity.getSoapSerializationEnvelope(MainActivity.java:68)
                                                                           at com.example.joria.wsandroid.MainActivity.invocar(MainActivity.java:51)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284) 
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have probably solved this long ago, but this is for others who are facing the same problem.

Check the url that you are passing to the `Soap Object`

When the URL isn't correct or isn't working, then the `soap object` is not verified and hence the error occurred.

Hope this helps :)